# MYSQL bulk insert with dataSets

Tags: mysql

I've got 2 data sets .

DataSet A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ;
DataSet B = 13,15,16,17;
Is there a way to tell mysql for every item from DataSet A insert each value from DataSet B ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a dataset? Is this a table? Something in-memory you have? Something else?

Comment: Is not a table, i've got those id's in an excel.

Comment: If your datasets are in excel, then why do you want to do this in mysql? If you want to do this task in mysql, you need to get the source data into mysql first.